# How to remove javascript code duplication on UpdatePanel refreshing in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, refresh, updatepanel, dopostback

Javascript code doesn't work after Updatepanel refreshed if it's not handled. There are a few ways to handle the case. I preferred one of them that has implementation like below;

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 **Javascript code...**

 var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
 if (prm != null) {
  prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
   if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {

     **Duplicated Javascript code, same as above**

   }
  });
 }
</script>
```

However, i don't want to write same javascript codes two times. So, how can i solve this problem?

**Update:** I don't want to call functions in the section. How to locate functions in the section without duplication?

Answer (score 1):

You put the code in a function, and call the function from both places.

```
// The first call
doSomething();

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm != null) {
    prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
    if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {

        // The second call
        doSomething();
    }
}

function doSomething() {
    // Code goes here
}
```

If the function needs informatino from the place where you call it, define parameters to the function (`function doSomething(param1, param2)` etc.) and pass arguments in when you call it (`doSomething("I'm the first", "I'm the second")`, etc.).

Comment: But there are some ajax requests and callback functions. How can i implement those? Like;

`$("#element").autocomplete({
                            source: function (request, response) {
                                $.ajax({....`

Also click function; `$('div.detailfilterbtn').click(function () {}`

Comment: @CeylanB.: Those would just be the code in `doSomething`.

Comment: I have a problem with functions those have parameters. For example; this is the function `function GetSelectedItem(lnk)` and it's called from HTML element like; `onclick="GetSelectedItem(this);"` So, i need to locate this function in panels update section. So how can i do this?

Comment: @CeylanB.: That's a new and different question. After giving it a go, if you're still stuck, post a question with a [mcve] describing what you need to do and the trouble you're having doing it.